# Dynamically Set Title On Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

```
    var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        'Update': function() {
          alert(clientCode);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });

    $(".edit").click(function() {
      myval = $(this).parent().children('td:nth-child(1)').text();
      dlg.dialog('open');
      return false;
    });
```

How do I take "myval" and have it as the title of the dialog?  I've tried passing it as an argument when doing `dlg.dialog('open', myval)` and no luck.  I've also tried passing it as a parameter but with no luck either.  I'm probably doing things in the wrong way, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create the dialog in the click-event and use this to set title:

something like this:

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
  myval = $(this).parent().children('td:nth-child(1)').text();

  var dlg = $("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: myval,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
      'Update': function() {
        alert(clientCode);
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });

  dlg.dialog('open');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
$("#your-dialog-id").dialog({
    open: function() {
        $(this).dialog("option", "title", "My new title");
    }
});
```